# Hide Confirm Form Resubmission PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms

After I submit a form, and I click the back button, the page displays the confirm form resubmission page. Instead of that, I actually just want the browser to display the form itself. It there a way to do that? Here is a part of my code below, and it works except that it will not stop refreshing. I just want it to refresh once when you click the back button.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
<form method = 'post' action = 'submitPost.php?section=$section'>
<textarea rows='10' cols='100' name = 'post'></textarea> </br>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser security policy - when you want to go back to a page you loaded using the `POST` http verb it will always ask you for confirmation.

Comment: Okay now that you answered the why, can you answer the how part too? As in, how to work around this problem? Would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is - you can't. The long answer involves changing your application logic, that I know too little about to be able to really help. One possible solution is: once you POST something, work with it, and then redirect the user using a `Location` header, this way the back button will not be broken, as it will not require form resubmission.